# Is there a way to call a custom Twitter endpoint using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to pull some data from Twitter in Python. I'd like to pull data from the `statuses/retweeters/ids` endpoint, however, it doesn't look like Tweepy has this endpoint built-in.

Is there a way I can call a custom endpoint so that I can use this endpoint and not just the API.retweets() endpoint in Tweepy that pulls retweets? I'm looking to grab individual user IDs of people who retweeted a specific tweet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at tweepy library code and how API methods are defined, I guess you could try this:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.binder import bind_api

# OAuth process
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('key', 'secret')
auth.secure = True
auth.set_access_token('token', 'token_secret')

# Creation of the interface
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Call of the custom endpoint
bind_api(
    api=api,
    path='/statuses/retweeters/ids',
    method='GET',
    allowed_param=['id', 'count', 'cursor', 'stringify_ids'],
    require_auth=True
)
```